# index is out of range after filtering an array

Tags: swift

I am trying to filter a song array so it only has songs where the song artistName is the same as ArtistName(Which is always the selected artist). When I run my app it throws an **Fatal error: Index out of range** even though in my debug console `artistSongs` has 4 elements. I don't understand how id be getting this crash.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    retriveData()
    
    //Register nib
    topSongTableView.register(TopSongTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: TopSongTableViewCell.topSongCell)
    
    ArtistPicture.image = artistCover
    ArtistLabel.text = ArtistName
    
    
    //Assign TableView to self
    topSongTableView.delegate = self
    topSongTableView.dataSource = self
}
//Define number of rows in topSongsTableView
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

// songs of artist
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TopSongTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TopSongTableViewCell
    let artistSongs = songs.filter{ $0.artistName == ArtistName }
    print(artistSongs)
    cell.TopSongLabel.text = artistSongs[indexPath.row].cleanName //CASH
    cell.SongImage.image = UIImage(named: artistSongs[indexPath.row].cover)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: $0.artistName == ArtistName , what's the type of artistName? and ArtistName is a class?

Comment: @luffy_064 ArtistName is a variable string that is filled when a user selects an artist from another table view. The point of this is to only have the songs that have that artist name.

Comment: you should never perform the filter inside cellForRow. Move your filter method to viewDidLoad or any other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your tableView `topSongTableView` expects to display 5 rows (you hard coded it) but when you're dequeuing your cells, you also filter `artistSongs` at the same time (it shouldn't be done here) and this produces in your case an array with less than 5 elements (4 in your case).

So here in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, you're trying to dequeue more cells than elements in `artistSongs`.

Let's say `let artistSongs = songs.filter{ $0.artistName == ArtistName }` produces an array of 3 elements only but your table view expects 5, when you dequeue your cells and try to access the song with `artistSongs[indexPath.row]`, it's gonna work for the first 3 rows and then it will crash (your current crash).

Your solution is to filter the artist songs somewhere else, say in `viewDidLoad`, and then use this array to populate your table view safely:

```
// ADD THIS
var filteredSongs: [Song]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    [...]

    // ADD THIS
    self.filteredSongs = songs.filter{ $0.artistName == ArtistName }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // CHANGE THIS
    return self.filteredSongs.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TopSongTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TopSongTableViewCell
    // REMOVE THIS
    //let artistSongs = songs.filter{ $0.artistName == ArtistName }
    // REMOVE THIS
    //print(artistSongs)
    cell.TopSongLabel.text = self.filteredSongs[indexPath.row].cleanName
    cell.SongImage.image = UIImage(named: self.filteredSongs[indexPath.row].cover)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am sure the your solution is right but it seems like your declaring a new array `var artistSongs: [ArtistSong]()`. I still need the data from the `songs` array to show up in my table view.

Comment: I am getting this error on `self.artistSong` line **Cannot assign value of type '[Songs]' to type '[String]'**

Comment: I've updated the example and renamed artistSongs by filteredSongs to be more clear. From what I understand you have a songs array somewhere in your view controller, and you want to filter this array thanks to ArtistName, and then display those filtered songs in your table view - hence why I declared a new array that your table view can safely use.

Comment: `var filteredSongs: [Song]()` solved my issue in the previous comment. Thanks! Especially for pointing out that I should filter my array in the viewDidLoad.